# Ceiling lights going out

Tags: electrical

About 3 months ago, I was carrying one 1inch pvc pipe through my mudroom to the basement when I bumped the pvc pipe into the ceiling fan in the mudroom. We didn't notice till the end of the day that the fan and light didn't work. Didn't really think too much about it it cuz the fan is pretty old. Got up the next morning and the light and fan worked. Since then, it has stopped working then mysteriously it would work. It is tied into the hallway ceiling light, light above the kitchen sink and 2 outside lights. They all randomly go off and then come back on whenever they want. BUT....now they won't come back on at all.
We have checked all switches, connections, etc and all is good. 
What are we missing?

Comment: *"What are we missing?"* Obviously, it's the things you haven't checked, yet. So now go check those. For example, the breaker at the entrance panel might be a start.

Comment: A self-correcting intermittent problemis frustrating. So it must be an almost connected daisy-chained line to a wirenut in the ceiling that relaxed then fused open to a slightly wider gap upon working with  oxide buildup.  A DMM helps to identify where the power is/isn't.

Comment: I agree with Tony, it is a daisy chain issue, since you wacked the fan you may have dislodged some wires. This is really common with back stabs but I would be looking at the wires in the fan and ceiling Light locations,  first the fan since you whacked it. A loose wire nut or broken wire will probably be found it can be on the black hot or white white if in the U.S.